# How get entire Git log history

Tags: git

When I do

```
git log
```

it only displays the last 4 commits, no matter how many there is. And I do know there is more than that, made very recently.

I have also tried to do

```
git log -x
```

(x>4), several tries with different x.

but no success, still only the last 4 commits are displayed.

Any idea ?

Comment: maybe try `git --no-pager log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git --no-pager log
```

This should print to stdout, the logs for you.

You can also output it to a file using:

```
git --no-pager log > log.txt
```